Error when using powershell AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store Value Using PowerShell's 'aws ssm get-parameter'?
I'm trying to fetch a parameter value from the AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store using PowerShell. Using the 'aws ssm get-parameters'. But I'm encountering issues.
Here's the code snippet I'm using:
function get_param_value($parameter){
    aws ssm get-parameters --name $parameter --with-decryption | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.Parameters[0].Value }
}

$server = get_param_value("/webhost/db/host")
Write-Output "server: $server"


Error:
+     aws ssm get-parameters --name "$parameter" --with-decryption | Co ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Can someone help me identify what might be wrong with this code or suggest a better approach to retrieve the parameter value using PowerShell's AWS CLI? Any insights or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
